# How to console.log exactly thing i need using forEach method

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 50 users.
So then i've a method showById: (should log into console user object that is matched by id, in case we unable to find user it should log “Unable to find user with id: __”);
Here is what i have:

```js
const users = [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Abner",
    "last_name": "Glaisner",
    "gender": "Male",
    "language": "Tswana"
    },
    {
      //...
    }]




    class UserList {
      constructor(users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    showNames() {
        users.forEach(function (user) {
            console.log(user);
            return this;
        })
    }

    showById(id) {
        users.forEach(function (user) {
            if (id === user.id) {
                console.log(user.first_name);
            } else {
                console.log(`Unable to find user id: ${id}`);
            }
        })
    }
    }
```

I expect the output of ONE object with current user, but what i have now is current object and 49 times "Unable to find user id: __";

Comment: I think forEach is the problem, forEach is executing its body by each item, 49 times id will be different. Try to use a for and return after you find the user or log the message out of the for if user doesn't exist

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the [Array `find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
showById(id) {
    let found = users.find(user => user.id === id);
    if (!found) {
        return console.log(`Unable to find user id: ${id}`);
    }
    console.log(found.first_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `forEach` will evaluate every item. It does not have an exit condition.

Instead, use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which stops when it finds a match:

```
showById(id) {
  let user = users.find(u => u.id === id);
  let output = user ? user.first_name : `Unable to find user id: ${id}`;
  return console.log(output);
}
```

```js
const users = [{"id": 1,"first_name": "Abner"},{"id": 2,"first_name": "John"}];

function showById(id) {
  let user = users.find(u => u.id === id);
  let output = user ? user.first_name : `Unable to find user id: ${id}`;
  return console.log(output);
}

showById(2);
showById(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your `if/else` block is INSIDE the `forEach` loop, so no matter what happens with that specific `user`, something will be logged to the console.

To fix this, you'll have to use another variable to keep track of whether that user has been found yet. Then, once that user is found, set that variable to be true, and only print `unable to find user id` if it's still false AFTER the loop.

```
showById(id) {
    let found = false;
    users.forEach(function (user) {
        if (id === user.id) {
            console.log(user.first_name);
            found = true;
            break; // not sure if you can break out of forEach loop
        }
    })
    if(!found) {
      console.log(`Unable to find user id: ${id}`);
    }
}
```